# How do I make a public reply to a particular post in an Emacs bug report?

Tags: emacs-development

I am looking at the thread of a particular Emacs bug report through the [bug-gnu-emacs archives](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/). Suppose I want to make a public reply to one of the posts in the thread. On the web page of the post, I see a button I can use to reply:

[image: reply via email]

If I click on the button, my email client will fill in the post author's personal email address in the "To" email field (e.g. `john.smith@example.com`). If I actually send the email, will the reply be made public? I want to make a public reply. How can I ensure that I am making a public reply?

I thought that I have to send replies to `123456@debbugs.gnu.org` (where `123456` represents the bug report number), so do I need to add `123456@debbugs.gnu.org` to the "CC" field or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. I never noticed those buttons on the web page before.

Yes, if you click that button it will open your mail client with only the person you're replying to in the `To` list.

To have the mail also go to the bug list (for that bug thread) you need to also include the bug number in the `To` list (or the `Cc` list, I think), in this form: `12345@debbugs.gnu.org`, just as you guessed.

---

You might even want to file an enhancement request to have the button also address the bug thread. (Using `M-x report-emacs-bug` might be sufficient for that, even though the web site is more general than just Emacs; dunno.)

Comment: If not mistaken, you would also need to set the `In-Reply-To:` header to the correct value in order to reply to the correct message. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/reply-to-mailman-archived-message

Comment: @Flux: I don't think that's correct. But I'm no expert on this. (Perhaps it depends on your mail client etc.?) In my experience, using `Reply All` in my mail works, and that just puts all of the recipients in `To:` or `Cc:`, as far as I know.

Comment: That's because your email client sets the `In-Reply-To:` header for you when you reply to an email that is already in your inbox. The question here is about replying to a post that one is seeing on a webpage. In this case, I think one would need to manually fill in the `In-Reply-To:` header with the correct value. It appears that this value can only be obtained from a hidden input in the HTML source of the webpage.

Comment: I see. In know next to nothing about such things. Please consider adding such info as a separate answer, to either answer the Q completely or complement my answer. I can't speak to that part, as I know nothing about it. Thx.

Comment: This is all very confusing because there is a bug in the GNU mailing list archives that has not been fixed in years. There is a mistake in the code that generates the "reply via email to" button, which makes the button quite useless for replying to threads. Refer to this mailing list thread: [Source code for "reply via email" on lists.gnu.org](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/mailman/2020-05/msg00003.html)